# 3d max collada with animation and texture not working with threejs

Tags: three.js, 3dsmax, collada

I have the collada pump example working fine. I'm now trying to export an animated dice with 1 texture but in the threejs I only see the shape of the dice with no texture. The animation works fine.

Also the lighting on the dice looks wrong.

I can  load the collada file in other program with no problems.

I'm using this version of threejs: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r72/three.js

anyone?

ADDED: I have create an example with a cube and one texture. In this example you can see that the texture is not on the cube: http://sigmaphp.dk/threejscollada.zip

Comment: You have to show your code, otherwise there is nothing to help you with.

Comment: ok. i have put an example together as simple as possible. This example has a cube with one texture mapped to each side of the cube (a smiley face). all the files needed should be in the zip file: http://sigmaphp.dk/threejscollada.zip

Comment: I also face the same problem